# SAMSUNG G. J710 RAM Capacity - 2GB or 3GB

Tags: samsung, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-j7

[In this post1](http://www.gsmarc.com/samsung/galaxy-j7/compare/galaxy-j7-2016/) it's stated that Sam J710 has 3GB of RAM (only 2GB of RAM in India).
[This post2](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_j7_(2016)-7870.php) says that it only has 2GB of RAM.

I bought the J710 model over the net a couple of days ago, which was produced for the european market and it has only 2 GB of RAM.

So, is this a description error in post 2 or why does it tell it has 3GB of RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what PDAdb listed and Samsung official websites said, only the Chinese variants (J7108 and J7109) have 3GB of RAM: [Samsung J7108 (Chinese)](http://www.samsung.com/cn/consumer/mobile-phones/smart-phone/galaxy-j/SM-J7108ZDDCHM), while other versions, including vanilla J710F, have 2GB: [Samsung J710 (French)](http://www.samsung.com/be_fr/consumer/mobile-phone/smartphones/smartphones/SM-J710FZWNPRO).